# Execute Scheduler in a fixed hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I want to execute this Job 2 times every day:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void myScheduler() {
        System.out.println("Test print");
    }

}
```

First time at 11:00 and second time at 14:00.

Is there a way to configure these hours?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [**CRON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) expressions to schedule task executions at given days/hours:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

In your example it would look as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 11,14 * * *")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 11,14 * * *")
```

This means

```
At second :00, at minute :00, at 11am and 14pm, of every day
```

You can generate it here https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 11,14 * * *")
```